# ChildNodes,length error

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

I try to loop through all the nodes in a div.
I use this code to have access to all the nodes in the div.

```
var div = document.getElementById('thedivId');
var childs = div.childNodes
```

and then i try to loop through it using `childs.length`

but in the console when i run it i am getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null

I cant understand why this happens, I know that isn't an array, but the node list has the property length, and i have seen it used in here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp

Comment: Maybe you run this before your DOM is ready, meaning that `thedivId` doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

The most probably answer is that when you run that, DOM is not ready, as Ismael said above